# PostgreSQL: export resulting data from SQL query to Excel/CSV

Tags: postgresql, file-io, postgresql-copy

I need to export the resulting data from a query in PostgreSQL to Excel/CSV.
I use `PostgreSQL 8.2.11`.

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  relative path not allowed for COPY to file
In statement:

COPY (select distinct(m_price) from m_product)TO '"c:\auto_new.txt"';
```

Comment: The name is `PostgreSQL` or `Postgres` for short. There is no `Postgre`.

Comment: You only need to double-quote the filename if it includes whitespace or special characters. Not necessary for `'C:\\auto_new.txt'`. (Not wrong, though.). There is

Comment: i tried giving >TO 'C:\\auto_new.txt' but the same error

Comment: There is also a space missing before `TO`. Not sure whether PostgreSQL 8.2 cares. It would still work in 9.0.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Example with Unix-style file name:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM tbl) TO '/var/lib/postgres/myfile1.csv' format csv;
```

Read the [manual about `COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/sql-copy.html) (link to version 8.2).
You have to use an *absolute path* for the target file. Be sure to double quote file names with spaces. Example for MS Windows:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM tbl)
TO E'"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Tech\Desktop\\myfile1.csv"' format csv;
```

In **PostgreSQL 8.2**, with [`standard_conforming_strings = off`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) per default, you need to double backslashes, because `\` is a special character and interpreted by PostgreSQL. Works in any version. It's all [in the fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/sql-copy.html):

> ***filename***
>
> The absolute path name of the input or output file. Windows users might need to use an `E''` string and double backslashes used as path separators.

Or the modern syntax with [`standard_conforming_strings = on`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729) (default since Postgres 9.1):

```
COPY tbl  -- short for (SELECT * FROM tbl)
TO '"C:\Documents and Settings\Tech\Desktop\myfile1.csv"' (format csv);
```

Or you can [also use forward slashes](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2004-09/msg00272.php) for filenames under Windows.

An alternative is to use the [meta-command `\copy` of the default terminal client `psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html).

You can also use a GUI like [pgadmin](http://pgadmin.org/) and copy / paste from the result grid to Excel for small queries.

Closely related answer:

- [Copy results from a PostgreSQL view in one DB to a table in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022061/copy-results-from-a-postgresql-view-in-one-db-to-a-table-in-another/8025412#8025412)

Similar solution for MySQL:

- [Exporting MYSQL data into Excel/CSV via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706093/exporting-mysql-data-into-excel-csv-via-php/7706164#7706164)

Comment: COPY (SELECT * FROM tbl) TO 'C:/Documents and Settings/Tech/Desktop/myfile1.csv';  SQL error:

ERROR:  relative path not allowed for COPY to file

Comment: @soul: I suspect the whitespace in your filename. See my amended answer.

Comment: @soul: ah .. Windows needs backslashes. See amended answer. (I use Debian.)

Comment: will try pgadmin and let u know @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: not able to copy in windows? what might be the issue with the query

Comment: @soul: Please amend your question with the exact SQL statement you use and the error message you get.

Comment: Do you have write permission in the c: root directory ?

Comment: Yup i got the  administrator privileges .. so i got the permission

Comment: @soul: With the switch to Windows and it's backslashes, we have triggered another effect: `\\` is a special character an needs to be escaped. (Just like I had to in this comment.) See my amended answer!

Comment: SQL error:

ERROR:  relative path not allowed for COPY to file
In statement:
COPY (select distinct(m_

Comment: @soul i am facing the same problem , got any fix ? :)

Comment: @sanre6 : nope just directly downloaded using the export button

Comment: @sanre6: Always remember that `COPY` handles files local to the *server*. If your client is on a different machine, use the meta-command `\copy` of the **psql** client or some other tool like **pgAdmin**.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter , hey i did not know that . But , still doesn't work even with \copy using pgadmin version 8.4. same error as mentioned in the post :(

Comment: There is a horrible bug is Windows  PostgreSQL   the test for an absolute path  the code just  looks for a '/'    see port.h            #define is_absolute_path  (     filename   )                                                        #define IS_DIR_SEP  (     ch   )      ((ch) == '/')
Value:

( \
    IS_DIR_SEP((filename)[0]) \
)

Comment: How to use \copy command? to query the data and save in csv file?

Comment: @AKIWEB: Follow my link above and read the manual. If something is still unclear, ask a *question*. Comments are not the place.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I got the same error as ghostman on Windows and I have no whitespace and use backslashes

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I can export a query result into CSV file using the COPY command , but one of the column data is a JSON data so when I open it in libreoffice it is split into different cells(since it had comma), any idea how to export the json data as is. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10):

In **PostgreSQL 9.4** to create to file CSV with the header in **Ubuntu**:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM tbl) TO '/home/user/Desktop/result_sql.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

Note: The folder must be writable.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM table) 
    TO E'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PostgreSQL\\8.4\\data\\try.csv';
```

In my case the problem was with the writing permission to a special folder (though I work as administrator), after changing the path to the original data folder under PostgreSQL I had success.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Several GUI tools like Squirrel, SQL Workbench/J, AnySQL, ExecuteQuery can export to Excel files.

Most of those tools are listed in the PostgreSQL wiki:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Answer (score 2):

If you have error like "ERROR: could not open server file "/file": Permission denied" you can fix it that:

Ran through the same problem, and this is the solution I found:
Create a new folder (for instance, tmp) under /home
$ cd /home
make postgres the owner of that folder
$ chown -R postgres:postgres tmp
copy in tmp the files you want to write into the database, and make sure they also are owned by postgres.
That's it. You should be in business after that.

Comment: Or you can copy to /tmp. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The correct script for postgres (Ubuntu) is:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM tbl) TO '/var/lib/postgres/myfile1.csv';
```

Comment: psql -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM tbl) TO '/var/lib/postgres/myfile1.csv';" don't forget to add db, user and password if require. -c flag give you option to run command from ubuntu(linux) terminal.

Comment: I want to put  quote around my string values. how can i? @Michael

Comment: You can try ' ' or "\""