# How to batch write a table that has 10 million plus records into separate gzip files-Python/Postgres/Airflow

Tags: python, postgresql, gzip, airflow, psycopg2

I have a table that has 10 million plus records(rows) in it. I am trying to do a one-time load into s3 by select *'ing the table and then writing it to a gzip file in my local file system. Currently, I can run my script to collect 800,000 records into the gzip file but then I receive an error, and the remainder records are obviously not inserted.

Since there is no continuation in sql (for example- if you run 10 limit 800,000 queries, it wont be in order).

So, is there a way to writer a python/airflow function that can load the 10 million+ table in batches? Perhaps theres a way in python where I can do a select * statement and continue the statement after x amount of records into separate gzip files?

Here is my python/airflow script so far that when ran, it only writers 800,000 records to the path variable:

```
def gzip_postgres_table(table_name, **kwargs):
    path = '/usr/local/airflow/{}.gz'.format(table_name)
    server_post = create_tunnel_postgres()
    server_post.start()
    etl_conn = conn_postgres_internal(server_postgres)

    record = get_etl_record(kwargs['master_table'],
                              kwargs['table_name'])
    cur = etl_conn.cursor()

    unload_sql = '''SELECT *
                        FROM schema1.database1.{0} '''.format(record['table_name'])

    cur.execute(unload_sql)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    column_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
    fp = gzip.open(path, 'wt')
    myFile = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    myFile.writerow(column_names)
    myFile.writerows(result)
    fp.close()
    etl_conn.close()
    server_postgres.stop()
```

Comment: Whats the error ?

Comment: Might be interesting, continuously fetching a smaller amount of data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60171679/fetching-data-from-postgres-database-in-batch-python

Answer (score 0):

The best, I mean THE BEST approach to insert so many records into PostgreSQL, or to get them form PostgreSQL, is to use postgresql `COPY`. This means you would have to change your approach drastically, but there's no better way that I know in PostgreSQL. [COPY manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html)

`COPY` creates a file with the query you are executing or it can insert into a table from a file.

> **COPY** moves data between PostgreSQL tables and standard file-system
>   files.

The reason why is the best solution is because your using PostgreSQL default method to handle external data, without intermediaries; so **it's fast and secure**.

`COPY` works like a charm with CSV files. You should change your approach to a file handling method and the use of `COPY`.

Since `COPY` runs with SQL, you can divide your data using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in the query. For example:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM country LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10) TO '/usr1/proj/bray/sql/a_list_of_10_countries.copy';
-- This creates 10 countries starting in the row 10
```

`COPY` only works with files that are accessible with PostgreSQL user in the server.

**PL Function (edited):**

If you want `COPY` to be dynamic, you can use the `COPY` into a PL function. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copy_table(
    table_name text,
    file_name text,
    vlimit text,
    voffset text
)RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    query text;
BEGIN
    query := 'COPY (SELECT * FROM country LIMIT '||vlimit||' OFFSET '||voffset||') TO '''||file_name||''' DELIMITER '','' CSV';
-- NOTE that file_name has to have its dir too.
    EXECUTE query;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
SECURITY DEFINER
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To execute the function you just have to do:

```
SELECT copy_table('test','/usr/sql/test.csv','10','10')
```

Notes:

- If the PL will be public, you have to check for SQL injection attacks.
- You can program the PL to suit your needs, this is just an example.
- The function returns VOID, so it just do the `COPY`, if you need some feedback you should return something else.
- The function has to be owned with user postgres from the server, because it needs file access; that is why it needs SECURITY DEFINER, so that any database user can run the PL.

Comment: Do you know how to copy the table to a csv file in 1million increments to a different file each time?

Comment: For that you can create a PL function. There you can create the file with a variable.