# How to export a PostgreSQL query output to a csv file

Tags: postgresql, shell, csv, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I'm having problem exporting my PostgreSQL output from a shell to a csv file.
My SQL script is called `script.sql`.

I typed the following command in my shell:

```
psql congress -af script.sql &> filename.csv
```

But when I opened the `filename.csv` file, values of all the columns are squeezed in one column in the Excel csv (see the attached screenshot).

Then I tried another way. I edited my `script.sql` to be:

```
Copy (Select * From ...) To '/tmp/filename.csv' With CSV;
```

Then I typed the following command in the shell within the database `dbname`.

```
\i script.sql
```

The output is:

```
COPY 162
```

Well, my output query has 162 rows.

So the 162 rows of my output table have been copied in the shell. How can I paste or move them to a csv file?

Or, if I'm going to use the filename.csv (screenshot is attached), how can I fix the format of that csv/Excel file?

[image: Screenshot of filename.csv]

Comment: when you open the file in Excel or other alike program, change delimiter to '|'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119297/postgresql-export-resulting-data-from-sql-query-to-excel-csv

Comment: See the more comprehensive answer here, which clarifies `\copy` (client-side) from `COPY` (server-side) queries in `psql`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Modern syntax:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM ...) TO '/tmp/filename.csv' (FORMAT csv);
```

> So the 162 rows of my output table have been copied in the shell. How
> can I paste or move them to a csv file?

The result ***is*** the CSV file. Open it with any spreadsheet program using matching delimiters. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

> The default is a tab character in text format, a comma in CSV format

The psql meta command [**`\copy`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) is a wrapper around the SQL `COPY` function. It writes and reads files local to the client (while `COPY` uses files local to the server) and does not require superuser privileges.

See:

- [Export specific rows from a PostgreSQL table as INSERT SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815496/export-specific-rows-from-a-postgresql-table-as-insert-sql-script/12824831#12824831)
- [PostgreSQL: export resulting data from SQL query to Excel/CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119297/postgresql-export-resulting-data-from-sql-query-to-excel-csv)

Comment: `COPY` requires you to be a superuser. `\copy` can be used by regular users and seemed to have the same syntax

Comment: this will ignore headers in output by default?

Comment: @Spike yes. If you want the header, just use (format CSV, HEADER)

Answer (score 8):

Most previos answers are correct, here is more details and only for linux

1.Create a file like my_query.sql

```
\COPY (select * from some_table) TO '/tmp/some_file.csv' (format CSV);
```

2.Run this below command after you have updated the variables for your DB and file path.

```
psql "host=YOUR_HOST port=YOUR_PORT dbname=YOUR_DB user=YOUR_USER password=YOUR_PASS" -af my_query.sql
```

tip: be cautious of your free disk space you have available if you do a select * from your_table you might run out of space if have a large table.

Answer (score 2):

first copy your connection info into ~/.pgpass and

```
cat ip:port:dbname:user:pass > ~/.pgpass
chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass
psql -h serverip -U userid dbname -af test.sql | gzip > result.txt.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Going off on a bit of a tangent, there is another way too.

I use the following in a windows batch script: -

```
psql.exe -U %cUser% -h %cHost% -p %cPort% -d %cDB% -t -o "%dumpDir%\tables.txt" -A -c "SELECT table_schema, table_name   FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '%qSchema%';"
```

The trick is to remember the -A option. It suppresses whitespace padding of the data.

I do this to avoid permission errors from the COPY command shown above with the account running postgress not have the same permissions as the account running my scheduled batch file.

This gets me a list of tables in a given schema with results like:-

myschema|mytable1

myschema|mytable2

I then use the FOR batch command to process each line. If you REALLY wanted a CSV file, all you would need to do would be this:-

```
ECHO table_schema,table_name > %dumpDir%\tables.csv
FOR /F "delims=|" %%p in (%dumpDir%\tables.txt) DO echo %%p,%%q >> %dumpDir%\tables.csv
```

Probably not the most efficient of mechanisms, but works fine on small numbers of output rows.

Comment: I like `psql -c 'select * from table limit 5' -tAF,` which automatically produces csv.

Comment: Where you are using password

Comment: Unless you have `|` in your data in which case good luck