# Converting query result into CSV

Tags: postgresql, csv, jdbc, dropwizard, jdbi

I have a JDBI query that returns many columns from few tables which I need to write to a CSV file. How can I achieve this? I have a REST end point that receives POST of search criteria using which I am constructing a query to fire against the Postgres db. I am using Dropwizard and JDBI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`COPY TO`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html).

```
COPY (SELECT ... ) TO '/path/to/myfile1.csv' FORMAT csv;
```

You need superuser privileges if you want to write to a file. [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html#AEN74310)

> `COPY` naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers,
>   since it allows reading or writing any file that the server has
>   privileges to access.

Or you can send the output to `STDOUT` directly without saving to a file (possible without superuser privileges!).

To write the file on your client (can be separate from the DB server or not) use the meta-command [`\copy` of psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) encapsulating the same functionality. This does [*not* require superuser privileges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY):

> This means that file accessibility and privileges are those of the local user, not the server, and no SQL superuser privileges are required.

Details:

- [PostgreSQL: export resulting data from SQL query to Excel/CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119297/postgresql-export-resulting-data-from-sql-query-to-excel-csv/8119342#8119342)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a CSVWriter (OpenCsv) to write this. Doing that, next time you need to switch out your database solution, your application won't break (hopefully)

Comment: I can't use the `COPY` due to superuser privilege requirements. We are using SuperCSV which has `CsvResultSetWriter`. But, not sure how to achieve this as my actual query result is set of columns from few tables and I don't have to have `@RegisterMapper` class and I don't have one.

Comment: @Nikki: `\copy` of psql does not require superuser privileges. Consider added details.

Comment: @Nikki I would make the query return an object. I feel like an application call writing a file to disk straight from the DB is a weird approach. Then execute my call and use a normal CSVWriter to write the file