# How to add large amounts of seed data to a production DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My initial seed.rb was about 35,000 lines of code. I kept getting "process killed" before I could seed in on the VPS. So I ran the seed locally and did a sql_dump/sql_restore to get the initial data base loaded. I now have another ~35,000 lines of code to add data to the server, whats the best way to do this?

fyi: The production server how has user generated data, so I can't really follow the same process I did with the initial seed data.

Comment: This might be best solved interacting with the database directly. Which one do you use? Postgres for example has the ability to load CSV files directly with [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html). You can also add additional data through `pg_restore` or `psql -f` without wiping the existing content.

Comment: This question might help: _[Export specific rows from a PostgreSQL table as INSERT SQL script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815496/export-specific-rows-from-a-postgresql-table-as-insert-sql-script)_