# Postgres: Combining multiple COPY TO outputs to a postgres-importable file

Tags: postgresql, heroku, import, copy, export

I have my database hosted on heroku, and I want to download specific parts of the database (e.g. all the rows with id > x from `table 1`, all the rows with name = x from `table 2`, etc.) in a single file.

From some research and asking a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446068/download-partial-database-from-heroku) it seems that some kind of modified pg_dump would solve my problem. However, I won't be able to use pg_dump because I won't have access to the command line (basically I want to be able to click a button in my web app and it will generate + download the database file).

So my new strategy is to use the postgres [copy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) command. I'll go through the various tables in my server database, run `COPY (Select * FROM ... WHERE ...) TO filename` , where `filename` is just a temporary file that I will download when complete.

The issue is that this `filename` file will just have the rows, so I can't just turn around and import it into pgadmin. Assuming I have an 'empty' database set up (the schema, indices, and stuff are all already set up), is there a way I can format my `filename` file so that it can be easily imported into a postgres db?

Comment: I think you'll need to create an empty DB schema using your app, since it sounds like you're using schema generation. Then do row by row imports.

Comment: you can "import" data from that "filename" by running COPY TABLENAME from 'filename'... keep in mind while "exporting" that if you use one "filename" it will be overwritten by EACH copy statement

Comment: Another hiccup is that `filename` is resolved *on the server*; you will not have access to that filesystem. PostgreSQL does support copy `to stdout`; some drivers (e.g., Python's `psycopg2`) give you access to that. For example: `stmt.copy_to(sys.stdout, "(select * from my_table)")` or `stmt.copy_expert("copy (select * from my_table) to stdout csv header", sys.stdout)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on my comment about to/from stdout/stdin, and answering the actual question about including multiple tables in one file; you can construct the output file to interleave `copy ... from stdin` with actual data and load it via `psql`. For example, `psql` will support input files that look like this:

```
copy my_table (col1, col2, col3) from stdin;
foo    bar    baz
fizz   buzz   bizz
\.
```

(Note the trailing `\.` and that the separators should be tabs; you could also specify the `delimiter` option in the copy command).

`psql` will treat everything between the ';' and '.' as stdin. This essentially emulates what `pg_dump` does when you export table data and no schema (e.g., `pg_dump -a -t my_table`).

The resulting load could be as simple as `psql mydb < output.dump`.