# Import and overwrite duplicate rows

Tags: postgresql, import, duplicates, overwrite, psql

I'm importing some rows to my postgres database like so:

```
psql -U postgres import_test < 1432798324_data
```

Where my `import_test` is my database and `1432798324_data` file is just plain text formatted like:

```
COPY cars FROM stdin;
<row data>
<row data>
...
\.

COPY drivers FROM stdin;
<row data>
<row data>
...
\.
```

(I got the format for this plain text file from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474305/postgres-combining-multiple-copy-to-outputs-to-a-postgres-importable-file)).

This method works fine when I'm importing into a blank database. However, if the database isn't blank and during the import any duplicate rows are found I get an error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "car_pkey"
```

Is there any way I could modify my import command to force an overwrite if duplicates are found? In other words, if I'm importing a row and there's already a row with that id, I want my new row to overwrite it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can import into a temporary table.  Then you can delete rows that were already there before you copy over the new data:

```
create temporary table import_drivers as select * from drivers limit 0;

copy import_drivers from stdin;

begin transaction;

delete  from drivers
where   id in
        (
        select  id
        from    import_drivers
        );

insert  into drivers
select  *
from    import_drivers;

commit transaction;
```

Comment: So this code goes in my plain text file? I'll basically have a chunk of code like this for each table in my plain text?

Comment: And also, is there a more efficient way to do this, since some of these tables have millions of rows? This has to insert all the rows 2 times right?

Comment: I would just delete all the indices that need to be overwritten, before importing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this where you are constantly doing a bulk import (lets say daily) is to use table partitioning.

You would just add a time field to your cars and drivers table. The time field is the time when you do the import. Your primary key will have to change for both tables as a two tuple of your existing primary key and the time field.

Once you are done you then just drop older tables (if you are using a daily scheme then you would drop the previous day) or alternatively use `max(time_field)` in your queries.