# Replicate subset of db for staging purpose

Tags: postgresql, heroku, staging

I’ve currently been using these two commands to copy the db from production to staging:

```
URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a myapp-production)
heroku pg:copy "$URL" DATABASE_URL -a myapp-staging --confirm myapp-staging
```

Due to a swelling database I wonder for testing purposes how to replicate only a limited number of rows (of each table) to another database.

A naive solution could be:
1.  Download db production -> locally
2. Run script that wipes out data
3. 4 Upload db locally -> staging

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446068/download-partial-database-from-heroku) answers how to download an entire table of a database.