# pg_dump from view has no data in postgresql 10

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

`pg_dump --table=export_view --data-only --column-inserts mydb > export_view.sql`

pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 10.7 (Ubuntu 10.7-1.pgdg18.04+1)

[Export specific rows from a PostgreSQL table as INSERT SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815496/export-specific-rows-from-a-postgresql-table-as-insert-sql-script) and the postgresql documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pgdump.html) suggest it is possible to `pg_dump` from a view with the `--table` flag. If I export from the table directly I get the expected result (ie, data is exported). If I select from the view in psql I get the expected result. However whether I create a view or a materialized view and then try and `pg_dump`, I get only the normal `pg_dump` headers and no data. A commenter (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2036135/poshest) also appears to have faced the same issue in the above SO question, with no solution given.

If I `CREATE TABLE blah AS SELECT x, y, z FROM MYTABLE` then I can export fine. If I `CREATE VIEW blah AS SELECT x, y, z FROM MYTABLE` then the export is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As @bugmenot points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861721/pg-dump-from-view-has-no-data-in-postgresql-10/66228848?noredirect=1#comment117122485_66228848), version 13 (and above?) - the current at the time this answer is written - [indeed has clarification on what gets dumped](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgdump.html):

> As well as tables, this option can be used to dump the **definition**
> of matching views, materialized views, foreign tables, and sequences.
> **It will not dump the contents of views or materialized views**, and the contents of foreign tables will only be dumped if the
> corresponding foreign server is specified with --include-foreign-data.

(emphasis added).

So the answer (to myself) is: "You are not doing anything wrong, except that you incorrectly interpreted the documentation for Postgres <=12. What you want to do is not possible."

Answer (score 1):

Views do not store data, they provide a dynamic view onto it. When you include views in your dump, you will only get the view definition.

Comment: Thanks, I know what a view is (though `materialized view`s do actually store data, so if you're going for the pedagogical angle, you should probably include that restriction). There is absolutely no logical reason why `pg_dump` couldn't include data from the result of calling a view though, and the documentation referenced fails to make this clear at all.

Comment: Didn't mean to sound condescending, sorry if that seemed the case. The confusion seems to be about what pg_dump is dumping and what a database "is". The latest version of the docs has gotten a note about views btw: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html